# Are $ \cos z$ and $ \sin z$ bounded functions with $z$ a complex number?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Really I guess since , $\cos ^2 z+\sin^2 z=1$ for every complex number $z$ then they behave like that in $\mathbb{R}$  , Right ?

Comment: $cos^2z+sin^2z=1$ doesn't mean they're bounded when complex

Comment: in My guess sin z and cos z should lie in (-1,1)

Comment: not necessarily the case if $z$ is complex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formulas for the complex cosine and sine can be derived from Euler's formula
$$e^{iz} = \cos(z) + i \sin(z)
$$
By substituting $-z$, and using that $\cos$ is even and $\sin$ is odd, one obtains
$$e^{-iz} = \cos(z) - i \sin(z)
$$
Thinking of this as a system of two equations in two unknowns, solving gives
$$\cos(z) = \frac{1}{2} (e^{iz} + e^{-iz})
$$
and 
$$\sin(z) = \frac{1}{2i} (e^{iz} - e^{-iz})
$$
From this you can see that $\cos(z)$ is unbounded along the imaginary axis, because
$$\cos(iy) = \frac{1}{2} (e^{-y} + e^y)
$$
and similarly for the $\sin$ function.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to look at this is from the perspective of Liouville's theorem: If $f(z)$ is a holomorphic function, defined on all of $\Bbb C$, and $f(z)$ is bounded, then $f(z)$ is constant.

Since $\cos z$ and $\sin z$ are nonconstant, holomorphic, and defined for every $z\in \Bbb C$ (the series defining them converge absolutely and uniformly on arbitrarily large compact subsets of $\Bbb C$), they are unbounded by Liouville's theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Using Picard’s little theorem and the knowledge that $\sin z$ and $\cos z$ are entire (i.e. holomorphic for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$, we can also conclude that $\sin z$ and $\cos z$ are unbounded. Picard’s little theorem states that an entire function $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ takes on every value in $\mathbb C$ with at most one exception.